# JavaScript - wait until element loaded on website using Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a Chrome extension that **clicks elements on a website,** but some of the elements appear after the check and the code doesn't work. I need to make the **function wait until the selected element is loaded**.

And **NOT wait in delays in seconds** like on `setTimeout` function.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Can be done with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```
function handleSomeDiv(someDiv) { 
    console.log("div was handled");
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, mutationInstance) {
    const someDiv = document.getElementById('some-div');
    if (someDiv) {
        handleSomeDiv(someDiv);
        mutationInstance.disconnect();
    }
});


observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree:   true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let element = document.getElementById('elementId')
while (element === null) {
    console.log('Waiting for element')
    element = document.getElementById('elementId')
}

// Perform operation with element
```

Comment: Nice, but if you have multiple elements, you can't add that to all of them...

Comment: You can use || to wait for more elements:

while (element1 === null ||  element2 === null ||  element3 === null)

Comment: I mean, if your making tons of `document.getElementById`'s, you can't put them all into a while loop, with the `element = document.getElementById('id');`

Comment: It will depends on the situation, if you are sure the element will exist after the page is load your approach is perfect, if not no.

Comment: Caution: 1) If "element" never appears, you have a non ending loop there. 2) is not async => execution after the loop is on hold 3) cpu greedy => takes as much as possible processing power

Comment: Won’t this also block the entire thread in perpetuity if the element never appears?

Comment: If the element is compulsory for the extension to work and never appears could be posible to setup a setTimeout function to cancel the while loop and show an error.

Comment: @esqew  The tab or even the browser will maybe crash at some point. Opera (guess all modern browsers) seems to be able to handle such loops. The tab is freezed and I managed to close it after a few seconds. But I was not able to do anything inside the tab.

Comment: There is not a magic script that will works ok for all situations (Not magic bullets)

Answer (score -1):

There are **2** ways to do this:

#### window.onload:

HTML:

```
<p id="pElement">Hello</p>
```

Javascript:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById("pElement").innerHTML+=", world!"
}
```

#### document.addEventListener('load')

HTML:

```html
<p id="pElement">Hello</p>
```

Javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('load',()=>{
  document.getElementById("pElement").innerHTML += ", world!";
});;
```

Comment: It is possible that the element does not exist when the page is finished loading, as in this example

document.addEventListener('load',()=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{ 
    const newElement = document.createElement('h1')
    newElement.setAttribute('id', 'elementID')
    document.appendChild(newElement)
  }, 50000)
})

Comment: @ManuelMB the question asks how to find the element on **HTML**, not javascript.

Comment: the question is:

Javascript wait until element loaded on website using chrome extension

Answer (score -1):

- You can try `setInterval` this method will be working all the time in the page and when your condition is true it's will execute it but be careful when use it - because of this method will be working all the time in the page so you need to add condition to exacute it just one time

> Example

```
var check = false;
setInterval(function () {
   if(document.getElementById("id") !== null && check === false) {
        document.getElementById("id").click();
        check = true;
    }
}, 1000)
```

- this will be check every second and when you condition is true it's will execute it just one time
- if you removed check condition it's will execute this code every second